# How to instantiate generic classes

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface:

```
public interface ICrawlService<T> where T : SocialPostBase
{
    Task<int> Crawl(int accountId, Disguise disguise, ISocialAccountRepository socialAccountRepository, ISocialRepository<T> socialRepository, ISocialCrawlJobRepository jobRepository, IInstrumentationRepository instrumentationRepository);
}
```

My social repository is:

```
public interface ISocialRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<SocialPostCollection<T>> List { get; }
    Task Add(SocialPostCollection<T> entity, string type);

    Task AddPosts(List<T> entity, string type);

    void Delete(SocialPostCollection<T> entity);
    void Update(SocialPostCollection<T> entity);
    T Find(string profileName, MediaType type);
}
```

I am looking for a polymorphic design so I can instantiate different classes into a single type. Something like:

```
var socialRepo = new SocialRepository<Video>(configration.CosmosDBServiceEndpoint, configration.CosmosDBSecret, configration.CosmosDBDatabaseId);
var socialRepo2 = new SocialRepository<Post>(configration.CosmosDBServiceEndpoint, configration.CosmosDBSecret, configration.CosmosDBDatabaseId);

ICrawlService<SocialPostBase> crawlService;

crawlService = new CrawlYoutubeProfileService();
var id = await crawlService.Crawl(jobId, null, _socialAccountRepo, socialRepo, _socialCrawlJobRepo, instrumentationRepo);

crawlService = new CrawlAnotherProfileService();
var id2 = await crawlService.Crawl(jobId, null, _socialAccountRepo, socialRepo2, _socialCrawlJobRepo, instrumentationRepo);
```

However it will not accept the base class for the generic parameter, I get following error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'SocialCrawlServices.CrawlYoutubeProfileService' to
>   'SocialCrawlServices.ICrawlService'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So how do you make a generic polymorphic design? Is that not possible?

Comment: define your interface with ICrawlService<out T>, than you can assign derived classes of the given type also, so for you types derived from SocialPostBase.

Comment: WHen doing so my Repository fails: Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'ISocialRepository<T>

Comment: Than put the "out" there too. Of course they have to fit. Another option would be to use Crawl<T> and making the interface non-generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that not possible?

No, it's possible. You just need to add `out` before your generic parameter in `ICrawlService`.

```
public interface ICrawlService<out T> where T : SocialPostBase
```

See [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Answer (score 0):

The error says "An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)". The answer is to explicitly cast the implementing class as the interface:

```
crawlService = (ICrawlService<SocialPostBase>)new CrawlYoutubeProfileService();

crawlService = (ICrawlService<SocialPostBase>)new CrawlAnotherProfileService();
```

This should work as long as `CrawlYoutubeProfileService` and `CrawlAnotherProfileService` have type arguments that implement `SocialPostBase`, like this:

```
class YoutubePost : SocialPostBase
{

}

class CrawlYoutubeProfileService : ICrawlService<YoutubePost>
{

}
```