# How to create a design service pattern that can take generic repository as input?

Tags: c#, generics

Notice this is related to this post, but I have an extended question. The related question answers the specific generic part.

[How to instantiate generic classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59307469/how-to-instantiate-generic-classes?noredirect=1#comment104817714_59307469)

First I have my models:

```
public class BasePost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Video : BasePost
{
    public int VideoPro { get; set; }
}


public class Post : BasePost
{
    public int PostProp { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want a repository that can only take types of BasePost:

```
public interface IRepo<out T> where T : BasePost
{
    void Add(BasePost post);

}

public class Repo<T> : IRepo<BasePost> where T : BasePost
{
    public void Add(BasePost post)
    {

    }
}
```

I need to be able to inject the repository into a service. I have different services where some are specialized for posts and some for videos:

```
public interface IService<out T> where T : BasePost
{
    void Run(IRepo<BasePost> repo);
}

public class FacebookService : IService<Post>
{
    public void Run(IRepo<Post> repo)
    {

    }
}
```

Here comes my first problem:

> 'FacebookService' does not implement interface member
>   'IService.Run(IRepo)'

My final goal is to have multiple service I can add to a common variable like:

```
IService service = null;
IRepo repo = null;
if (txtInput.Text == "Facebook")
{
    service = new FacebookService<Post>();
    repo = new Repo<Post>();

}
else
{
    service = new YoutubeService<Video>();
    repo = new Repo<Video>();               
}

service.Run(repo);
```

Summary:
I have a repo that writes to a cosmos DB. So it can take any type that derives from BasePost. That repo I want to pass to different services. Each service however is restricted to handle one model (video or Post).

Because the data is written to a cosmos db I want to save all the properties of the specialized type (video/post). So I would like to avoid a lot of casting back and forward between the base class and the specialized classes.

I may have designed this totally wrong or over complicated it. All input are welcome.

Comment: What does the `IService<T>` interface look like? Is there a non-generic version of the interface as well?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that one. I added it to main post.

Comment: `FacebookService`'s `Run` method needs to take a `IRepo<BasePost>`, or you need to change the interface to use the generic argument (and add a generic argument restriction)

Comment: I actually tried generic version of the interface like: public interface IService<out T> where T : BasePost
{
    void Run(IRepo<T> repo);
}. But then I get error: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'IService<T>.Run(IRepo<T>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you previous question you were able to solve the case issue using `out`. But you can't use the `T` in method argument due to language feature restriction of `out`. You can tweak the design to use your `T` for assignable methods. Also important point use interfaces when using covariants.

e.g. Your interfaces would look like:

```
public interface IPost
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public interface IRepo<out T> where T : IPost
{
    void Add(BasePost post);
}

public interface IService<T> where T : IPost
{
    IRepo<T> Repository { get; }
    void Run();
}
```

Implement a base class to handle the repository initialization via constructor, to enforce it as dependency.

```
public class BasePost : IPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Repo<T> : IRepo<BasePost> where T : BasePost
{
    public void Add(BasePost post)
    {

    }
}

public abstract class Service : IService<IPost>
{
    public IRepo<IPost> Repository { get; private set; }

    public Service(IRepo<IPost> repository)
    {
        this.Repository = repository;
    }

    public abstract void Run();
}
```

You use the base class to implement the services:

```
public class FacebookService : Service
{
    public FacebookService(IRepo<IPost> repository) : base(repository)
    {
    }

    public override void Run()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now you can initialize the services object and assign them to your IService interface.

```
    IService<IPost> service = null;
    IRepo<IPost> repo = null;
    if (input == "Facebook")
    {
        repo = new Repo<Post>();
        service = new FacebookService(repo);
    }
    else
    {
        repo = new Repo<Video>();
        service = new YoutubeService(repo);
    }
    service.Run();
```

Comment: I think you skipped the Repo part?

Comment: @ThomasSegato I have updated the answer to utilize the generic repository in a service class.

Comment: In your `Run()` method implementation you may have to cast object to inherited type  e.g. Post or Video to access model specific properties.

Comment: But if I cast it to BasePost I will lose the properties from specialized object when adding it to cosmos db.

Comment: It depends on the method of serialization used in COSMOS db. I'm not familiar with it. But that's a completely different problem, Give it a try let see what happens.

Comment: I allready tried thats how I started. Skipped all the generic part and just the inheritance part. I will let the post run for tommorow. And then I properly just make some "hard coded" classes.

Comment: I ended up using this approach. Using a constructor my services can have different inputs. Thanks all.